# How to compare two date in querybuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, date-format

I'm trying to create a search form and I need to compare selected date with the others dates in database. The selected date has this format **(dd/mm/yyyy)** and the dates saved in database have this format **(mm-dd-yyy)**

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->leftJoin('t.image', 'i')->addSelect('i')
        ->leftJoin('t.country', 'country')->addSelect('country')
        ->leftJoin('t.destination', 'destination')->addSelect('destination')
        ->leftJoin('t.airport', 'airport')->addSelect('airport')
        ->Where('t.agence = :agence')
        ->setParameter('agence', $agence);
   //.........

    if (!empty($departureDate)) {
        $qb->andWhere('t.departureDate <= :departureDate')
            ->setParameter('departureDate', new \Datetime($departureDate));
    }
return $qb;
```

this query show me this error if the selected day is **upper of 13**

```
DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed 
to parse time string (13/02/2015) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character
```

and if it is **less of 13** , the query does not give me the correct results

Comment: I guess 
`$departureDate = new \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $departureDate)->format('m-d-Y');` is what you need

Comment: I got this error `Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'` and phpStorm give me this error `incorrect access to static class member`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by setting query like this :

```
if (!empty($departureDate)) {
        $date = new \DateTime;
        $qb->andWhere('t.departureDate <= :departureDate')
            ->setParameter('departureDate', $date->createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$departureDate));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong internationalization configuration: your date is parser as `mm/dd/yyyy`. You need to change this behavior:

```
$departureDate = new \DateTime::createFromFormat('dd/mm/YY', $departureDate)
```

Comment: `if (!empty($departureDate)) {
   $qb->andWhere('t.departureDate <= :departureDate')
    ->setParameter('departureDate',  new \DateTime::createFromFormat('dd/mm/YY', $departureDate)));
  }`      

I got this error `Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'` and phpStorm give me this error `incorrect access to static class member`

Answer (score 0):

Check this 
`$departureDate = new \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $departureDate)->format('m-d-Y');`

Comment: I got this error `Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'` and phpStorm give me this error `incorrect access to static class member`

Comment: Hey there. Please make sure that your answer actually works :)